# Must energy providers cease collection on active complaints and pay £500 for ones referred to the energy ombudsman?

Tags: england-and-wales, energy

https://www.instagram.com/tv/Cgz4SgUFhnJ/

Specifically, is it true that energy companies are not allowed to undertake any debt collection activity on one's account after one has raised a complaint against them with the energy ombudsman?

And, is it true that they must pay £500 for every unresolved complaint?

From an internet link:

> undaunted
> Forumite 1.9K POSTS
> 27 September 2011 at 3:51PM edited 27 September 2011 at 3:53PM
> I'd broadly agree with Backfoot - though I think Ombudsman are perhaps inclined not to be over generous with compensation.

> As to fee structures, taken from Ofgem report in the link below

> Fee structure
> 4.24 The costs of the Energy Ombudsman Service are met by Members through membership and case fees. In 2009/10 the case fee was set at £334 per case considered whilst annual membership fees were £61,000 for each of the large energy suppliers, £16,500 in total for network companies and £150 per company for small suppliers. In the interests of simplicity the case fees are clearly not cost reflective, as the case fees for some of the networks complaints requiring expert assistance for resolution, are higher. As far as we understand from our discussions, this is not perceived by Members as an issue.

> http://www.ofgem.gov.uk/Sustainability/Cp/Cr/Documents1/Independent%20review%20of%20the%20Energy%20Ombudsman.pdf

Comment: Can you please give a more descriptive title?

Comment: https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/discussion/3510915/cost-of-taking-complaint-to-energy-ombudsman

Comment: https://www.switch-plan.co.uk/save-on-energy-bills/government-grants/energy-ombudsman/